# Can we change index.html and main.ts to something else in angular?

Tags: angular

As a part of learning process ,I tried to change the index.html and main.ts file name to something else and made the necessary changes in the angular.json to reflect the same as below

```
options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ngrx-tut",
            "index": "src/indexs.html",
            "main": "src/mains.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

but when i tried to build the app ,I got an issue as follows

```
ERROR in error TS6053: File 'D:/angularD/src/main.ngtypecheck.ts' not found.
error TS6053: File 'D:/angularD/src/main.ts' not found.
```

Is there a way to change this index.html and main.ts file to something else and how? what changes part did i miss out on

Answer (score 2):

Also rename it inside `tsconfig.app.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/mains.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```